# Can't load libRlapack.so & libRblas.so under conda

Tags: r, conda, openblas

I built a conda env with all the R packages needed to run my code so I can share it with coworkers. Unfortunatly there are errors when loading packages :

> ```
> Loading required package: BiocParallel
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘DelayedArray’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
>  unable to load shared object '/work/pterzian/.conda/envs/methdiffR-test/lib/R/library/Matrix/libs/Matrix.so':
>   libRlapack.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> Error: package ‘DelayedArray’ could not be loaded
> In addition: Warning message:
> package ‘matrixStats’ was built under R version 3.6.3
> Execution halted
> ```

Investigating a bit around this issue brought me to find a probably bad workaround. I found it could be related to a symbolic link name issue :

```
$ cd /.conda/envs/myRenv/lib

$ ls -ltrh 'liblapack.so'
liblapack.so -> libopenblasp-r0.3.10.so

$ ls -ltrh 'libblas.so'
libblas.so -> libopenblasp-r0.3.10.so
```

Changing those links with the right name solved the problem of loading package and the code runs fine.

```
$ mv liblapack.so libRlapack.so

$ mv libblas.so libRblas.so
```

However as I expected when I rebuild the env after exporting the `yml` file it reproduce the error. Symbolic name in the `lib` folder still have to be renamed which is problematic when sharing the env.

The yml file :

```
name: myRenv
channels:
  - r
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - bioconductor-annotationdbi=1.48.0=r36_0
  - bioconductor-annotationfilter=1.10.0=r36_0
  - bioconductor-beachmat=2.2.0=r36he1b5a44_0
  - bioconductor-biobase=2.46.0=r36h516909a_0
  - bioconductor-biocfilecache=1.10.0=r36_0
  - bioconductor-biocgenerics=0.32.0=r36_0
  - bioconductor-biocparallel=1.20.0=r36he1b5a44_0
  - bioconductor-biomart=2.42.0=r36_0
  - bioconductor-biostrings=2.54.0=r36h516909a_0
  - bioconductor-bsgenome=1.54.0=r36_0
  - bioconductor-bsseq=1.22.0=r36he1b5a44_0
  - bioconductor-chippeakanno=3.20.0=r36_0
  - bioconductor-delayedarray=0.12.0=r36h516909a_0
  - bioconductor-delayedmatrixstats=1.8.0=r36_0
  - bioconductor-dss=2.34.0=r36h516909a_0
  - bioconductor-edger=3.28.0=r36hc6cf775_1
  - bioconductor-ensembldb=2.10.0=r36_0
  - bioconductor-genomeinfodb=1.22.0=r36_0
  - bioconductor-genomeinfodbdata=1.2.2=r36_0
  - bioconductor-genomicalignments=1.22.0=r36h516909a_0
  - bioconductor-genomicfeatures=1.38.0=r36_0
  - bioconductor-genomicranges=1.38.0=r36h516909a_0
  - bioconductor-go.db=3.10.0=r36_0
  - bioconductor-graph=1.64.0=r36h516909a_0
  - bioconductor-hdf5array=1.14.0=r36h516909a_0
  - bioconductor-iranges=2.20.0=r36h516909a_0
  - bioconductor-limma=3.42.0=r36h516909a_0
  - bioconductor-multtest=2.42.0=r36h516909a_0
  - bioconductor-protgenerics=1.18.0=r36_0
  - bioconductor-rbgl=1.62.1=r36he1b5a44_0
  - bioconductor-regioner=1.18.0=r36_0
  - bioconductor-rhdf5=2.30.0=r36he1b5a44_0
  - bioconductor-rhdf5lib=1.8.0=r36h516909a_0
  - bioconductor-rhtslib=1.18.0=r36hdb70ac9_1
  - bioconductor-rsamtools=2.2.0=r36he1b5a44_0
  - bioconductor-rtracklayer=1.46.0=r36h516909a_0
  - bioconductor-s4vectors=0.24.0=r36h516909a_0
  - bioconductor-summarizedexperiment=1.16.0=r36_0
  - bioconductor-xvector=0.26.0=r36h516909a_0
  - bioconductor-zlibbioc=1.32.0=r36h516909a_0
  - _libgcc_mutex=0.1=conda_forge
  - _openmp_mutex=4.5=1_gnu
  - _r-mutex=1.0.1=anacondar_1
  - binutils_impl_linux-64=2.35=h18a2f87_9
  - binutils_linux-64=2.35=hc3fd857_29
  - bwidget=1.9.14=0
  - bzip2=1.0.8=h516909a_3
  - ca-certificates=2020.6.20=hecda079_0
  - cairo=1.16.0=hcf35c78_1003
  - certifi=2020.6.20=py39h079e4ff_2
  - curl=7.68.0=hf8cf82a_0
  - fontconfig=2.13.1=h86ecdb6_1001
  - freetype=2.10.4=he06d7ca_0
  - fribidi=1.0.10=h516909a_0
  - gcc_impl_linux-64=7.5.0=hd9e1a51_17
  - gcc_linux-64=7.5.0=he2a3fca_29
  - gettext=0.19.8.1=hf34092f_1004
  - gfortran_impl_linux-64=7.5.0=hfca37b7_17
  - gfortran_linux-64=7.5.0=ha081f1e_29
  - glib=2.66.2=he1b5a44_0
  - graphite2=1.3.13=he1b5a44_1001
  - gsl=2.6=h294904e_0
  - gxx_impl_linux-64=7.5.0=h7ea4de1_17
  - gxx_linux-64=7.5.0=h547f3ba_29
  - harfbuzz=2.4.0=h9f30f68_3
  - icu=64.2=he1b5a44_1
  - jpeg=9d=h516909a_0
  - kernel-headers_linux-64=2.6.32=h77966d4_13
  - krb5=1.16.4=h2fd8d38_0
  - ld_impl_linux-64=2.35=h769bd43_9
  - libblas=3.8.0=17_openblas
  - libcblas=3.8.0=17_openblas
  - libcurl=7.68.0=hda55be3_0
  - libedit=3.1.20191231=he28a2e2_2
  - libffi=3.2.1=he1b5a44_1007
  - libgcc-devel_linux-64=7.5.0=h42c25f5_17
  - libgcc-ng=9.3.0=h5dbcf3e_17
  - libgfortran-ng=7.5.0=hae1eefd_17
  - libgfortran4=7.5.0=hae1eefd_17
  - libglib=2.66.2=h0dae87d_0
  - libgomp=9.3.0=h5dbcf3e_17
  - libiconv=1.16=h516909a_0
  - liblapack=3.8.0=17_openblas
  - libopenblas=0.3.10=pthreads_hb3c22a3_5
  - libpng=1.6.37=hed695b0_2
  - libssh2=1.9.0=hab1572f_5
  - libstdcxx-devel_linux-64=7.5.0=h4084dd6_17
  - libstdcxx-ng=9.3.0=h2ae2ef3_17
  - libtiff=4.1.0=hc7e4089_6
  - libuuid=2.32.1=h14c3975_1000
  - libwebp-base=1.1.0=h516909a_3
  - libxcb=1.13=h14c3975_1002
  - libxml2=2.9.10=hee79883_0
  - lz4-c=1.9.2=he1b5a44_3
  - make=4.3=hd18ef5c_1
  - ncurses=6.2=he1b5a44_2
  - openssl=1.1.1h=h516909a_0
  - pandoc=2.11.0.2=hd18ef5c_0
  - pango=1.42.4=h7062337_4
  - pcre=8.44=he1b5a44_0
  - pip=20.2.4=py_0
  - pixman=0.38.0=h516909a_1003
  - pthread-stubs=0.4=h14c3975_1001
  - python=3.9.0=h2a148a8_4_cpython
  - python_abi=3.9=1_cp39
  - r-ade4=1.7_15=r36h7fa42b6_2
  - r-askpass=1.1=r36hcdcec82_2
  - r-backports=1.1.10=r36hcdcec82_0
  - r-base=3.6.2=h7ed4ef7_1
  - r-base64enc=0.1_3=r36hcdcec82_1004
  - r-bh=1.72.0_3=r36h6115d3f_1
  - r-biocmanager=1.30.10=r36h6115d3f_1
  - r-bit=4.0.4=r36hcdcec82_0
  - r-bit64=4.0.5=r36hcdcec82_0
  - r-bitops=1.0_6=r36hcdcec82_1004
  - r-blob=1.2.1=r36h6115d3f_1
  - r-callr=3.5.1=r36h142f84f_0
  - r-cellranger=1.1.0=r36h6115d3f_1003
  - r-clipr=0.7.1=r36h142f84f_0
  - r-codetools=0.2_17=r36h142f84f_0
  - r-cpp11=0.2.3=r36h142f84f_0
  - r-curl=4.3=r36hcdcec82_1
  - r-data.table=1.13.2=r36h0eb13af_0
  - r-dbi=1.1.0=r36h6115d3f_1
  - r-dbplyr=1.4.4=r36h6115d3f_0
  - r-desc=1.2.0=r36h6115d3f_1003
  - r-domc=1.3.7=r36hb0f4dca_0
  - r-dplyr=1.0.2=r36h0357c0b_0
  - r-ellipsis=0.3.1=r36hcdcec82_0
  - r-evaluate=0.14=r36h6115d3f_2
  - r-forcats=0.5.0=r36h6115d3f_1
  - r-foreach=1.5.1=r36h142f84f_0
  - r-formatr=1.7=r36h6115d3f_2
  - r-fs=1.5.0=r36h0357c0b_0
  - r-futile.logger=1.4.3=r36h6115d3f_1003
  - r-futile.options=1.0.1=r36h6115d3f_1002
  - r-generics=0.0.2=r36h6115d3f_1003
  - r-ggplot2=3.3.2=r36h6115d3f_0
  - r-glue=1.4.2=r36hcdcec82_0
  - r-gtools=3.8.2=r36hcdcec82_1
  - r-haven=2.3.1=r36hde08347_0
  - r-highr=0.8=r36h6115d3f_2
  - r-hms=0.5.3=r36h6115d3f_1
  - r-htmltools=0.5.0=r36h0357c0b_0
  - r-httr=1.4.2=r36h6115d3f_0
  - r-idr=1.2=r36_1003
  - r-isoband=0.2.2=r36h0357c0b_0
  - r-iterators=1.0.13=r36h142f84f_0
  - r-jsonlite=1.7.1=r36hcdcec82_0
  - r-lambda.r=1.2.4=r36h6115d3f_1
  - r-lifecycle=0.2.0=r36h6115d3f_1
  - r-locfit=1.5_9.4=r36hcdcec82_1
  - r-lubridate=1.7.9=r36h0357c0b_0
  - r-markdown=1.1=r36hcdcec82_1
  - r-matrixstats=0.57.0=r36hcdcec82_0
  - r-memoise=1.1.0=r36h6115d3f_1004
  - r-mime=0.9=r36hcdcec82_1
  - r-openssl=1.4.3=r36he5c4762_0
  - r-permute=0.9_5=r36h6115d3f_3
  - r-pillar=1.4.6=r36h6115d3f_0
  - r-pixmap=0.4_11=r36h6115d3f_1003
  - r-pkgbuild=1.1.0=r36h6115d3f_0
  - r-pkgload=1.1.0=r36h0357c0b_0
  - r-plogr=0.2.0=r36h6115d3f_1003
  - r-praise=1.0.0=r36h6115d3f_1004
  - r-prettyunits=1.1.1=r36h6115d3f_1
  - r-processx=3.4.4=r36hcdcec82_0
  - r-progress=1.2.2=r36h6115d3f_2
  - r-ps=1.4.0=r36h0eb13af_0
  - r-purrr=0.3.4=r36hcdcec82_1
  - r-r.methodss3=1.8.1=r36h6115d3f_0
  - r-r.oo=1.24.0=r36h6115d3f_0
  - r-r.utils=2.10.1=r36h6115d3f_0
  - r-rappdirs=0.3.1=r36hcdcec82_1004
  - r-rcurl=1.98_1.2=r36hcdcec82_0
  - r-readr=1.4.0=r36h1b71b39_0
  - r-readxl=1.3.1=r36hde08347_4
  - r-rematch=1.0.1=r36h6115d3f_1003
  - r-reshape2=1.4.4=r36h0357c0b_1
  - r-rlang=0.4.7=r36hcdcec82_0
  - r-rprojroot=1.3_2=r36h6115d3f_1003
  - r-rsqlite=2.2.1=r36h1b71b39_0
  - r-rstudioapi=0.11=r36h6115d3f_1
  - r-segmented=1.2_0=r36h6115d3f_0
  - r-seqinr=4.2_4=r36h0eb13af_0
  - r-snow=0.4_3=r36h6115d3f_1002
  - r-sp=1.4_2=r36hcdcec82_0
  - r-stringi=1.4.6=r36h0e574ca_2
  - r-stringr=1.4.0=r36h6115d3f_2
  - r-survival=3.2_7=r36hcdcec82_0
  - r-sys=3.4=r36hcdcec82_0
  - r-testthat=2.3.2=r36h0357c0b_1
  - r-tibble=3.0.4=r36h0eb13af_0
  - r-tidyselect=1.1.0=r36h6115d3f_0
  - r-tinytex=0.26=r36h6115d3f_0
  - r-vctrs=0.3.4=r36hcdcec82_0
  - r-venndiagram=1.6.20=r36h6115d3f_1002
  - r-whisker=0.4=r36h6115d3f_1
  - r-xfun=0.18=r36hcdcec82_0
  - r-xml=3.99_0.3=r36hcdcec82_1
  - r-xml2=1.3.2=r36h0357c0b_1
  - r-yaml=2.2.1=r36hcdcec82_1
  - r-zeallot=0.1.0=r36h6115d3f_1002
  - readline=8.0=he28a2e2_2
  - sed=4.8=hbfbb72e_0
  - setuptools=49.6.0=py39h079e4ff_2
  - sqlite=3.33.0=h4cf870e_1
  - sysroot_linux-64=2.12=h77966d4_13
  - tk=8.6.10=hed695b0_1
  - tktable=2.10=h555a92e_3
  - tzdata=2020d=h516909a_0
  - wheel=0.35.1=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - xorg-kbproto=1.0.7=h14c3975_1002
  - xorg-libice=1.0.10=h516909a_0
  - xorg-libsm=1.2.3=h84519dc_1000
  - xorg-libx11=1.6.12=h516909a_0
  - xorg-libxau=1.0.9=h14c3975_0
  - xorg-libxdmcp=1.1.3=h516909a_0
  - xorg-libxext=1.3.4=h516909a_0
  - xorg-libxrender=0.9.10=h516909a_1002
  - xorg-renderproto=0.11.1=h14c3975_1002
  - xorg-xextproto=7.3.0=h14c3975_1002
  - xorg-xproto=7.0.31=h14c3975_1007
  - xz=5.2.5=h516909a_1
  - zlib=1.2.11=h516909a_1010
  - zstd=1.4.5=h6597ccf_2
  - r-assertthat=0.2.1=r36h6115d3f_0
  - r-cli=1.1.0=r36h6115d3f_0
  - r-colorspace=1.4_1=r36h96ca727_0
  - r-crayon=1.3.4=r36h6115d3f_0
  - r-dichromat=2.0_0=r36h6115d3f_4
  - r-digest=0.6.18=r36h96ca727_0
  - r-fansi=0.4.0=r36h96ca727_0
  - r-gridextra=2.3=r36h6115d3f_0
  - r-gtable=0.3.0=r36h6115d3f_0
  - r-labeling=0.3=r36h6115d3f_4
  - r-lattice=0.20_38=r36h96ca727_0
  - r-lazyeval=0.2.2=r36h96ca727_0
  - r-magrittr=1.5=r36h6115d3f_4
  - r-mass=7.3_51.3=r36h96ca727_0
  - r-matrix=1.2_17=r36h96ca727_0
  - r-mgcv=1.8_28=r36h96ca727_0
  - r-munsell=0.5.0=r36h6115d3f_0
  - r-nlme=3.1_139=r36ha65eedd_0
  - r-pkgconfig=2.0.2=r36h6115d3f_0
  - r-plyr=1.8.4=r36h29659fb_0
  - r-r6=2.4.0=r36h6115d3f_0
  - r-rcolorbrewer=1.1_2=r36h6115d3f_0
  - r-rcpp=1.0.1=r36h29659fb_0
  - r-scales=1.0.0=r36h29659fb_0
  - r-utf8=1.1.4=r36h96ca727_0
  - r-viridislite=0.3.0=r36h6115d3f_0
  - r-withr=2.1.2=r36h6115d3f_0
```

Comment: There is an inconsistency between your system (and its _external_ LAPACK and BLAS libraries that you show) and the system which built the `DelayedArray` package which appears to have led it to have a hardwired depdency on the (shipped with R and built unless external LAPACK/BLAS select) `libRlapack` and `libRblas` (note the 'R' here).  That appears to be the problem.  I know little about Conda but I suggest you look / ask there.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thank you for the suggestion. I know very little about conda so I may ask there.

Comment: I would try removing the `r` in the channels. Improper channel mixing is a common cause of shared library issues. Bioconda expects `conda-forge > bioconda > defaults`, so putting `r` as highest priority mixes in a bunch of builds that the Bioconda package builds (i.e., everything from Bioconductor) are not tested to be compatible with. However, you will also need to remove all the package build specifications from the YAML, since those typically lock in the channel. Perhaps you can export a new YAML with `conda env export --from-history` instead.

Comment: @merv Thank you. I actually found these same suggestions on another SO question. I tried but it didn't solve the errors. I am beginning to think it might come from the system where I am working (slurm on centOS 7).
 I will try building the env on my pc to see if the error persists.

Comment: @PaulEndymion do you have a minimal version of the environment YAML you could share? E.g., is `conda create -n foo bioconductor-delayedmatrixstats=1.8.0` sufficient to create an environment with exactly the same issue?

Comment: I cannot replicate: I see no issues on either Mac OS X or CentOS 7 machines loading libraries mentioned in OP in environments with `bioconductor-delayedmatrixstats=1.8.0` installed and the recommend Bioconda channel priorities.  Here is [the environment I get on CentOS 7](https://gist.github.com/mfansler/3ce26420603adfa02348882db78618e3).

Comment: @merv I tried to build your environment and it actually solved the `libRlapack.so` issue when loading `DelayedArray` ! However there are some missing dependency like `edgeR` for which I already saw the same issue happening while testing. I will try adding them to your test environment and test my code.

Comment: Everything looks fine to share the yaml file now. Actually I think the problem was coming from previously installed packages in my home `Rlib` folder. As soon as I deleted the folder it didn't reproduced the error. Now I should warn users to remove this folder as well. There is also a part of the pipeline code checking for packages and installing them if they are missing, those are installed in this `Rlib` folder, maybe I should consider remove this code now it runs with conda... Anyway I appreciate the help @merv !